# os.rename() disrupted due to unwanted "/", which won't get replaced

Tags: python, encoding, filepath, file-rename, pypdf

I am trying to rename files using information obtained through `PdfFileReader`, from the `PyPDF2` library. Sometimes, the information (in this case the title obtained with `reader.metadata.title` contain backslashes ("/"), which disrupt the renaming process as they are considered directory levels in the path I indicate in `os.rename()` as destinations paths. I have tried to replace the backslashes with "-" by applying the `os.replace()` method on the strings obtained but for some reason, this doesn't work resulting in a `FileNotFoundError` when I try to rename. I have double checked and the type of the variable containing `reader.metadata.title` is `str`, so in theory `os.replace()` method should successfully apply. Is the "`TOC/TOC`" shown in my output example below some sort of encoding that needs to be dealt with differently? Thanks.

My code:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader


for pdf_file in os.listdir(downloads_path):
    if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf"):
        current_file_path = os.path.join(downloads_path, pdf_file)
        reader = PdfReader(open(current_file_path, "rb"))
        new_name_pdf_file = reader.metadata.title
        new_name_pdf_file.replace("/", "-")

        # output example: 'Outside Back Cover - Graphical abstract TOC/TOC in double column/Cover image legend if applicable, Bar code, Abstracting and Indexing information'
        print(new_name_pdf_file)
        new_pdf_destination = os.path.join(destination_path, new_name_pdf_file)
        os.rename(current_file_path, new_pdf_destination)
```

Output error example:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/Documents/temporary_downloads_folder/Outside-Back-Cover---Graphical-abstract-TOC-TOC-in-double-column-C_2022_Nano.pdf' -> '/Users/me/Documents/destination_folder/Outside Back Cover - Graphical abstract TOC/TOC in double column/Cover image legend if applicable, Bar code, Abstracting and Indexing information.pdf'
```

Comment: Look at the target filename complained of in the error message. Does the folder `Outside Back Cover - Graphical abstract TOC/TOC in double column` exist in `destination_folder`? If not your code will have to create it first. If it's  your intention for those elements to be part of the filename then those slashes also need to go.

Comment: @BoarGules yeah that’s the problem. I am trying to replace the slashes because they are part of the filename, which i am trying to do with `new_name_pdf_file.replace("/", "-")` but it’s not working. I am not sure why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```py
new_name_pdf_file.replace("/", "-")
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It does not change the string `new_name_pdf_file` points to. In fact: It can't do that. Strings are immutable in python. They cannot be changed. Instead, it creates a new string with the replacement done.

Change the line to

```py
new_name_pdf_file = new_name_pdf_file.replace("/", "-")
```

and it should work.